# Why these Issues when installing Qt Creator afresh?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, cmd, qt-creator

After a couple of days of trying to get Qt Creator to build a Windows GUI project I received from a colleague, I decided to remove my previous installation and re-install Qt from a clean slate.

Using the latest "Community" version installer from the Qt website, I selected the Qt toolchain version 5.11.2, including MinGW 5.3.0 32-bit, Qt Sources and Qt Scripts.

I did not select any MS Visual Studio related toolchains. However, on my machine there is an updated VS Community installed.

After installation was done, I started Qt Creator, and before even selecting a project to open, I get these errors reported in the **Issues** pane (in the image, also is the Help/About popup):

[image]

Why does Qt look for the MSVS scripts, and moreover, why is it not able to run `cmd.exe` as reported by the 1st error. The VS scripts are exactly in the reported path.

How should I eliminate theses errors?

Comment: Qt doesn't look for the scripts. Qt Creator does - it's an IDE. It needs to know what compilers are available on your system. As for the failure: you'd have to build Qt Creator itself, debug it, and break on the location where the error is produced.

Comment: @KubaOber - thanks. You're right about the distinction between Qt and Qt Creator. As for building Qt Creator locally, I think I'd pass the pleasure. One would expect that a massively used IDE would install w/o such problems (at least offer flavors in the installer) and certainly not require a step-wise debug session. Anyway, it happens that this particular error did not affect my ability to build my actual project (up to legitimate errors in the project's build process).

Comment: Close Qt Creator, then delete C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\QtProject folder, and then run Qt Creator. Now from Tools/Options setup the kits and compile your project. Hopefully everything will start working.